# What's the best way to create a menu in jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an application that contains a menu with links to the several pages and I would like to know what's the best way to implement it.

One [solution](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/global-header-for-all-pages) is to create the menu on all pages via JavaScript, but it would duplicate menus when it should have just one global to all pages.

Another [solution](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/global-header-for-all-pages) would be to create a div outside the framework but this way would not be taking any advantage of the features of the framework.

Comment: Try using Sencha Touch instead of jQuery Mobile :3

Comment: did you find anything yet? any useful answer? JQM says using the same ID for header/footer is the solution, but its a double implementation like you said.

Comment: Have you checked out http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/touchoverflow.html?  Right now, it only works on iOS5 but might help if that's all you're targeting.

Answer (score 1):

At the present version of jQueryMobile 1.0a4.1 the only [solution](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/global-header-for-all-pages) I found was creating a div outside the jQueryMobile page structure.

HTML:

```
<div id="global-header">Header</div> 

<div data-role="page">
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#global-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:99999;
}

.ui-page {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This works nice, but any way to get jQuery Mobile styles to be applied to elements in the header?  Once I do above, jQuery mobile doesn't do anything with the elements inside the header.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared [this post](http://www.roughlybrilliant.com/three_ways_to_implement_a_global_menu_in_jquery_mobile) specifically for this question,  It deals less with fixed headers and footers (since I generally believe them to be misguided wastes of already limited real estate) and more about dealing with global navigation in general.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the plugin I'm writing, called [multiview](https://github.com/frequent/multiview).

It's still work in progess, but you can set a *global header/footer* by placing it inside the wrapper page, but outside any panels you are using.

Let me know if this would fit your need. I'm slowly progressing towards bug-fixing stage.