# jQuery Mobile Static Headers

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQM application that uses the header as a navigation bar. The problem I'm having is that the page transitions (specifically slide) move the header along with the content as one "page". I'm looking for a way to keep the header static during page transitions.

I've checked the API and can't seem to find anything. Has anyone figured out a way to accomplish this? Is it even possible with jQM?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to build your own header that is not part of a `<div data-role="page">` element. Generally you add your header/footer as a child of the `<div data-role="page">` element but that makes them transition with the rest of the page.

To remove the header from transitions you can absolutely position your custom header at the top of the page and then add padding to the `data-role="content"` div elements so the header does not hide any content.

```
<style>
#my_header {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 50px;
    z-index  : 1000;
    overflow : hidden;
}
[data-role="content"] {
    padding-top : 50px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">...</div>
    <div id="my_header">...</div>
</body>
<!-- Notice the header div is not nested within any data-role="page" divs -->
```

I haven't tested this but I do something similar for site-wide menus and it works great. The pages should transition behind the header and the header should stay in-place.

Answer (score 2):

[This link to the jquerymobile site](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html) outlines how to do this 'properly'. Probably new in 1.20 (I'm just getting on board with this so not certain). Works better than the padding solution for me, but only if you don't need the same static instance of the header which is probably what the OP was after, as it keeps state. Handy link, anyhow.

Comment: Great solution! Solved my problem perfectly and is very simple relative the accepted answer.

Comment: Apologies, I should have pasted the relevant info into the answer and included the link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  In JQM you're working with page structures of which the header and footer are part.  Page transitions are then applied to the entire page.  I tend to set the page transition to fade to make it less obtrusive.

Answer (score 0):

You need an external library like iScroll-4 (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) or Scrollability for a all-platform solution. I would prefer iScroll, works smooth and valid.

For iOS5 explicitly you could use position:fixed in CSS for your header. In combination with overflow: touch;.

The JQM api allows also static headers, but the way they realized it is like you describe it, headers and footer disappear and appear again because it recalculates the screen-size to adapt the position of the header/footer. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

Additionally here is a good topic on global menu (adaptable to global header): [What's the best way to create a menu in jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664770/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-menu-in-jquerymobile) in their is a perfect link: http://www.roughlybrilliant.com/three_ways_to_implement_a_global_menu_in_jquery_mobile

Does this help?