# jquery mobile, still menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, menu, navigation

currently working with jquery mobile cause the transitions look nice.
I've designed a menu on the header that will navigate to different pages(the menu style will change according to the page it's on)
I want my menu to be still, so only the content page will change and transition nicely without resetting the whole page.
I know how to change the content with basic ajax, but it won't animate it like jquery mobile api offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this will work out of the box-- because each page has it's own header. You could write some javascript that will load the menu into the header on a particular event (ie pageshow). As far as animations-- it's possible you won't see them depending on the browser you are testing on. Safari is a pretty good emulator in terms of testing.

But again, the main issue of keeping the menu "static" throughout all pages, in my opinion is not a viable option.

This might be helpful:

[jQuery Mobile Static Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231660/jquery-mobile-static-headers)